# What are the differences between [allowed-topics] and [scope]?

Tags: discussion, scope, tag-synonyms

I see that we have two meta tags that are similar, if not synonym: [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope). Are they really different? If not, should we merge them?

See also on Meta Stack Exchange: [What is the difference between the “scope” and the “on-topic” tags on most child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299951/260800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged the tags and created a synonym, thanks.